# how to hide label if span id value is empty?

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

How can I hide label if span `id` value is empty? I need to hide a result but I can't find a solution.
if this `<input type="text" id="cap" name="cap" placeholder="   Name"/>` value is empty in index.html then dont show this level `<label id="t1w_1">Name</label>` on result.html
here my code

index.HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Input Form
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <form action="result.html" method="POST">
            <input type="text" id="cno" name="cno" placeholder="Count no.." autofocus required />
            <input type="text" id="cap" name="cap" placeholder="    Name"/>
            <input type="submit" onclick="handleSubmit()"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
function handleSubmit () {
    
    const cno = document.getElementById('cno').value;
    const cap = document.getElementById('cap').value;

    // to set into local storage
    /*localStorage.setItem("CNO", cno);
    localStorage.setItem("CAP", cap);*/
    
    sessionStorage.setItem("CNO", cno);
    sessionStorage.setItem("CAP", cap);
    return;
}
```

result.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script type="text/javascript" src="result.js" ></script>

<body style="margin: 100px;">

<span>: 6051670/S/23-24/210420230<span id="result-cno" /></span>/PS
<br>
<label id="t1w_1">Name</label>
<span id="result-cap"/></span>

</body>
</html>
```

result.js

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

    // Via Query parameters - GET
    /* const params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
    
    const cno = params.get('cno');
    const cap = params.get('cap');*/

    // Via local Storage
    /*const cno = localStorage.getItem('CNO');
    const cap = localStorage.getItem('CAP');*/
    
    const cno = sessionStorage.getItem('CNO');
    const cap = sessionStorage.getItem('CAP');
    
    document.getElementById('result-cno').innerHTML = cno;
    document.getElementById('result-cap').innerHTML = cap;
})
```

if this `<input type="text" id="cap" name="cap" placeholder="   Name"/>` value is empty then dont show this level `<label id="t1w_1">Name</label>` on result.html

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this.

You can create a CSS class that with display none that when applied will hide elements. Then use javascript to toggle that class on the element if the value is hidden.

```js
let cap = "";
let t1w_1 = document.querySelector("#t1w_1");
t1w_1.classList.toggle("hide",(cap == ""))
```

```css
.hide{display:none}
```

```html
<label id="t1w_1">Name</label>
```

You can also just use a basic if statement and set the display property to none to hide it in basic javascript.

```js
let cap = "";
let t1w_1 = document.querySelector("#t1w_1");

if(cap == ""){
  t1w_1.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<label id="t1w_1">Name</label>
```